# parsing string value within a string

Tags: java

I have to retrieve the value after `10` and before `TM` i.e `MJ` from the below string:

> ":XX /10/MJ/TM"

I am able to retrieve the value from below code:

```
String s=":XX: /10/MJ/TM *";
String[] arr = s.split("\\r?\\n?/");

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
```

Is there any effective way to do this?

Comment: What is the format of your string?  Is the field you're looking for always preceded by `/10/` and followed by `/TM`? Is it always the 3rd field where `/` is the field separator?

Comment: the for-loop is obsolete... unless you want to print it more than once

Comment: In your example, after `10` and before `TM` there is  `/MJ/`, not `MJ`. If your specifications were clear, I'd post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your string is fixed *(with respect to position and separator)*

```
String s=":XX: /10/MJ/TM *";
System.out.println(s.split("/")[2]); // MJ
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regexp with a group to capture the interesting bit:

```
String s=":XX: /10/MJ/TM *";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*10/(.*)/TM.*");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Warning: you should write code around your find() and group() call to avoid errors.

If you are sure about the / separator, you can also simplify the regex: ".*/(.*)/.*"

Answer (score 0):

Why for `loop` here??

Your code can simply post like this

```
    String s = ":XX: /10/MJ/TM *";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\r?\\n?/");
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
```

Comment: String s = ":XX: /10/MJ/TM *";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("10/")+3,s.indexOf("/TM")));